# VSCode NX Ошибка: Failed to start or connect to the Nx Daemon process

Tags: visual-studio-code, nx

Работаю на проекте, где для билда собственных библиотек используется NX.
При сборке проекта через NX столкнулся с данной ошибкой:

> Failed to start or connect to the Nx Daemon process

При этом некоторые библиотеки в проекте собираются нормально, а некоторые выдают подобную ошибку.
Не понимаю, из-за чего возникает подобная ошибка.

package.json:

```
"@nrwl/cli": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/cypress": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/jest": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/linter": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/nest": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/node": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/nx-cloud": "15.0.2",
"@nrwl/react": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/storybook": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/tao": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/web": "15.4.5",
"@nrwl/workspace": "15.4.5",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
Оказывается, начиная с версии NX 14.7.6 и выше происходит конфликт Nx с расширением VSCode Nx Console.

На данный момент у меня установлено: Nx Console v. 17.31.0

Чтобы нормально сбилдить библиотеки необходимо:

1. Отключить расширение Nx Console в VSCode
2. Перезагрузить VSCode
3. Выполнить билд необходимой библиотеки.